# Problems with VisualTreeHelper Hit test in landscape

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, hittest, visualtreehelper

I'm using the FindElementsInHostCoordinates method to find elements as the user swipes his finger across the screen. I'm noticing that it is reacting to if the phone was in portrait. For example - As I move my finger up it moves down, and as I move my finger to the right it moves left. It also only does something if I'm in the bottom half of the phone. So I think it if finding the coordinates that I'm hitting in landscape but acting as if I was in portrait. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host is always in portrait mode [by design](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/c646ebad-1cf8-4a8d-aae6-011da5ce1eae). However, you can read about a workaround in [this blog post](http://www.andybeaulieu.com/Home/tabid/67/EntryID/206/Default.aspx).

Comment: For some reason it's working on my emulator but I have the same problem on my phone?

Comment: Is you LayoutRoot at position 0,0?

Comment: Yes. Might it have to do with the fact that the emulator is running mango?

Comment: I'm not running Mango, so I can't test it. If you're creating a 7.0 project, it *should* be fine (might not be), but if you're creating a 7.1 project, maybe something has changed that's causing the code not to work.